# Lektor installation fails on MacBookPro OS X 10.6.8

Tags: macos, installation, lektor

I am trying to install Lektor on a MacbookPro with OS X 10.6.8.

Imagemagick and Python2.7 are already installed.

When I run the installation command:

```
curl -sf https://www.getlektor.com/install.sh | sh
```

The build process runs until it gets an error when building '_watchdog_fsevents' extension. The error is:

> cc1: error: -Werror=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future: No option -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future

I've cut and pasted the output just prior to the error into the following code section.

How should I overcome this?

```
  running build_ext
  building '_watchdog_fsevents' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/src
  gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -DWATCHDOG_VERSION_STRING="0.8.3" -DWATCHDOG_VERSION_MAJOR=0 -DWATCHDOG_VERSION_MINOR=8 -DWATCHDOG_VERSION_BUILD=3 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/watchdog_fsevents.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/src/watchdog_fsevents.o -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
  cc1: error: -Werror=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future: No option -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
  cc1: error: -Werror=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future: No option -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
  error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for watchdog
Failed to build watchdog
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your version of OS X is too old to support the installation of watchdog with the version of gcc you have.  If you cannot upgrade your OS X installation then I recommend installing a recent version of clang via brew and install lektor after exporting CC=clang.

Note though that Lektor is not tested for OS X < 10.9.

Comment: fwiw, it looks like the incompatibility with 10.6 was introduced in 0.8.2.  `pip install watchdog==0.8.1` will build on osx 10.6, and lektor seems to run on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be an updated version of Xcode in which you have not agreed to the license.  Try running this first:
sudo xcodebuild -license
scroll to the very bottom and it will allow you to type "agree".
This resolved the issue for me.